# Which harddrive would OS be installed on?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd

I recently bought a new computer, but I'm not very good at building so I ordered parts and got a Umart to make it for me, they said that they installed windows. I have two internal drives, one Samsung SSD 850 evo 500gb and a HP envy 5530 series 1.0 (2tb i think). I just booted for the first time, and it said select media store or boot media storage with the OS on it. I entered the UEFI and my 'boot option priorities' goes as

1.Hard drive

2.Samsung SSD

3.HP Envy

I'm not sure what to do from here, so if someone can help! Thanks :)

EDIT: Exact error shows:

```
Reboot and Select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot Device and press a key
```

Comment: This entirely depends on which drive contains Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drives on that list will be tried in sequence. If you have one OS only the sequence is not critical, it will boot anyway. The sane configuration would have OS on SSD so it should be your top (1.) priority. This way BIOS won't waste time for probing other devices.

Edit:
I haven't seen BIOS that would ask for boot device when there is OS somewhere on a drive that exists on boot priority list. There is probably no OS installed.

Edit2:
Your "BIOS" may be UEFI. There may be an option to change "legacy boot" vs "UEFI boot", try to change it, it may make a difference. Still, if someone installed OS they would (should!) leave that option the way it should be.

Comment: So are you saying that they haven't installed an OS?

Comment: Probably they have not. Try with SSD on the first position to be sure. You won't break anything just by changing these priorities.

Comment: Yes it is UEFI. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I can't find an option to change legacy to UEFI. My motherboard is Asus so its the Republic of Gamers UEFI/BIOS menu.

Comment: I have no access to a motherboard with this particular menu. I searched for its screens and I guess you should work with "Boot Device Control" option.

Comment: There's nothing like that here, however I found a menu called Boot/CSM with options: Launch CSM, Boot Device Control(woops there it is), Boot from Network Devices, Boot from Storage Devices and Boot from PCI-E. So I guess I change Boot Device Control from UEFI and Legacy OPROM to either Legacy OPROM only or UEFI only.

Comment: I would try this. Yet, all those options should be set properly in order to install OS (i.e. beforehand) and not changed later without a good reason. Either there is no OS or somebody has sabotaged your configuration. Any of these cases is a valid reason to complain and seek vendor help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38724/discussion-between-recon-and-kamil-maciorowski).

Answer (score 0):

If you install Windows on your SSD hard drive, you'll get better performance. Of course you can also choose to install Windows on HP Envy's built-in hard drive. When you get the error "Reboot and Select proper Boot device" at boot, it indicates that no operating system is installed on your selected disk, or your Windows is installed in Legacy/CSM mode while the BIOS is set to run in UEFI mode.

Learn the differences between UEFI and legacy BIOS mode:
http://www.howtogeek.com/175649/what-you-need-to-know-about-using-uefi-instead-of-the-bios/